# Repeating a function in Python a variable amount of times

Tags: python, repeat

For this code to work it has to repeat a variable amount (n) of times. It could change any time the program is run. I am extremely new to python and fairly new to programming in general, so I really don't know where to start.

```
def valueThree():
    name = input("What is the name?")
    valueOne = int(input("What is valueOne?"))
    valueTwo = int(input("What is valueTwo?"))
    valueThree = valueOne/valueTwo
    name_value = name, valueThree
    print(name_value)
n = int(input("How many times should valueThree() show up?"))
```

The program is supposed to execute `valueThree` n amount of times.

Answer (score 2):

You want a [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

```
for _ in xrange(n):
    valueThree()
```

Comment: For python3 this would just be `range`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
for x in xrange(n):
    valueThree()
```